# cordova webintent plugin isnt working

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I actually want to capture the weblink which can trigger my app to launch. 
I am using the code as given below. [written in AndroidManifest.xml].

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />    
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />                   
    <data
        android:host="mysite.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/_mobile/"
        android:scheme="http"                   
    />              
</intent-filter>
```

Launching of an app is a success when I try to visit "mysite.com/_mobile". Basically, the aforementioned link is actually a link to the mobile version of my main website. Now, if a user has the app installed, it should open the app rather than the mobile web page. So far, it works great. Now the problem is when I want to navigate to a specific page in an app. for example, "mysite.com/_mobile?productId=103" - this would open a page for productId=103 in mobile web view. But, incase the user has my app installed, how can I redirect him to this productId page in an app. 
I did some googling on this topic and stumbled upon a cordova plugin. I added this plugin, so called "Initsogar/cordova-webintent" [here](https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent). Now, I am using this code,

```
window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
    if(url !== "") {
        alert("URL was "+url);
    }
});
```

All I want is to get the uri which launched the app. I do not get the desired outcome. I tried to alert some value to check if this code is working or not, it seems its NOT. 
see the code that  i used for testing:

```
window.plugins.webintent.getUri(function(url) {
  alert(2);    
  if(url !== "") {                
     alert("URL was "+url);
  }         
});
```

Here, 2 is not alerted. I dont know whats wrong with this plugin. other than this, I have no clue where to start from. any help would be great. :)